# replace symbols, in factors, in a data frame, with dplyr mutate

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a data frame, and for various reasons I need to keep one of the elements as a factor and, maintaining the order of the levels, replace periods in the levels with spaces. Here's an example

```
library(tidyverse) library(stringr)

sandwich <- c("bread", "mustard.sauce", "tuna.fish", "lettuce", "bread")

data_frame(sandwich_str = sandwich) %>%
mutate(sandwich_factor = factor(sandwich)) %>%
mutate(sandwich2 = factor(sandwich_factor,
    levels = str_replace_all(levels(sandwich_factor), "\\.", " "))) %>%
mutate(sandwich3 = str_replace_all(sandwich_str, "\\.", " "))

print(sandwich_df)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 4    
>
> sandwich_str, sandwich_factor, sandwich2, sandwich3
>    <chr>           <fctr>,    <fctr>         <chr>,
> 1  bread            bread            bread     bread 
> 2  mustard.sauce    mustard.sauce   <NA>      mustard sauce 
> 3  tuna.fish        tuna.fish       <NA>      tuna fish
> 4  lettuce          lettuce         lettuce   lettuce 
> 5  bread            bread           bread     bread
> ```

So in this data frame:

`sandwich_str` is an element of characters

`sandwich_factor` is an element of factors

in `sandwich2` I tried replacing all of the periods in the levels of `sandwich_factor`. For whatever reason, this returns NA whenever there are periods.

in `sandwich3` I take the more simple approach of just replacing all of the periods in strings with spaces. This works substantially better.

So I'm wondering what isn't working in my attempt at sandwich2. I'd like it to look more like sandwich3. Any advice?

Comment: If you want to change the levels you need to use the "labels" argument in factor(), not the "levels" argument.

Comment: Ah. Right you are. That does seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @aosmith for posting this answer as a comment. I'll post it here as an answer so I can accept and close this.

The problem was that factor levels are defined with the flag *labels* rather than *levels*. So the correct way for me to have written this previously would be:

```
library(tidyverse) library(stringr)

sandwich <- c("bread", "mustard.sauce", "tuna.fish", "lettuce", "bread")

data_frame(sandwich_str = sandwich) %>%
mutate(sandwich_factor = factor(sandwich)) %>%
mutate(sandwich2 = factor(sandwich_factor,
    labels = str_replace_all(levels(sandwich_factor), "\\.", " "))) %>%
mutate(sandwich3 = str_replace_all(sandwich_str, "\\.", " "))

print(sandwich_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------

sandwich <- 
  c("bread", "mustard.sauce", "tuna.fish", "lettuce", "bread")

df <- 
  data_frame(sandwich_str = sandwich) 

# Convert periods to spaces -----------------------------------------------

df$sandwich_str <-
  df$sandwich_str %>%
  as.character() %>%
  str_replace("\\."," ") %>%
  as.factor()

# Print output ------------------------------------------------------------

df %>% 
  print()
```

Comment: I think this approach does not preserve the order of the factor levels, but rather results in them being re-ordered alphabetically. @aosmith's comment above, on the other hand, does solve the problem as requested.